# Does This Asp.Net WebAPI controller method get swapped out of app pool correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, c#-5.0

I've got a Post method in my webapi 2 controller that does an insert into a database but often has to retry for many seconds before it succeeds.  Basically, that causes a lot of sleeps between the retries. Effectively, it is running the code below.  My question is, is this code correct so that I can have thousands of these running at the same time and not using up my iis page pool?

```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {


        try
        {
            HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
            string json = await requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            //InsertInTable(json);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

*** Added By Peter As To Try Stephens's suggestion of Await.Delay.  Shows error that can not put await in catch.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXXX()
    {
        HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
        string json = await requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

        bool success = false;
        int retriesMax = 30;
        int retries = retriesMax;
        while (retries > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // DO ADO.NET EXECUTE THAT MAY FAIL AND NEED RETRY
                retries = 0;
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                // exception is a deadlock
                if (exception.Number == 1205)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    retries--;
                }
                    // exception is not a deadlock
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

*** More Added By Peter, Trying Enterprise block, missing class (StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy class not found)

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
        string json = await requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var retryStrategy = new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        var retryPolicy =
          new RetryPolicy<StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

        try
        {
            // Do some work that may result in a transient fault.
            retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(
              () =>
              {
                  // Call a method that uses Windows Azure storage and which may
                  // throw a transient exception.
                  Thread.Sleep(10000);
              });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // All the retries failed.
        }
```

*****Code that causes SqlServer to spin out of control with open connections

```
          try
          {
            await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
                async () =>
                {
                    // this opens a SqlServer Connection and Transaction.
                    // if fails, rolls back and rethrows exception so
                    // if deadlock, this retry loop will handle correctly
                    // (caused sqlserver to spin out of control with open
                    //  connections so replacing with simple call and
                    //  letting sendgrid retry non 200 returns)
                    await InsertBatchWithTransaction(sendGridRecordList);
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Utils.Log4NetSimple("SendGridController:POST Retries all failed");
        }
```

and the async insert code (with some ...'s)

```
   private static async Task
         InsertBatchWithTransaction(List<SendGridRecord> sendGridRecordList)
    {
        using (
            var sqlConnection =
                  new SqlConnection(...))
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            const string sqlInsert =
                @"INSERT INTO  SendGridEvent...

            using (SqlTransaction transaction = 
                  sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction"))
            {
                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("EventName", SqlDbType.VarChar);

                    sqlCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var sendGridRecord in sendGridRecordList)
                        {
                            sqlCommand.Parameters["EventName"].Value = 
                                GetWithMaxLen(sendGridRecord.EventName, 60);

                            await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "often has to retry for many seconds before it succeeds" - ouch. You might want to consider MSMQ or some similar operation queuing mechanism rather than rolling your own.

Comment: You could move the `await` call outside the try-catch block by setting `success` to true just after "retries = 0;", and then checking for success outside the try-catch block, if success then await...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. At the very least, you want to replace `Thread.Sleep` with `await Task.Delay`. `Thread.Sleep` will block a thread pool thread in that request context, doing nothing. Using `await` allows that thread to return to the thread pool to be used for other requests.

You might also want to consider the [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=pandp.50).aspx).

**Update:** You can't use `await` in a `catch` block; this is a limitation of the C# language in VS2013 (the next version will likely allow this, [as I note on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/await-in-catch-and-finally.html)). So for now, you have to do something like this:

```
private async Task RetryAsync(Func<Task> action, int retries = 30)
{
  while (retries > 0)
  {
    try
    {
      await action();
      return;
    }
    catch (SqlException exception)
    {
      // exception is not a deadlock
      if (exception.Number != 1205)
        throw;
    }
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    retries--;
  }

  throw new Exception("Retry count exceeded");
}
```

To use the Transient Fault Handling Application Block, first you define what errors are "transient" (should be retried). According to your example code, you only want to retry when there's a SQL deadlock exception:

```
private sealed class DatabaseDeadlockTransientErrorDetectionStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
        var sqlException = ex as SqlException;
        if (sqlException == null)
            return false;
        return sqlException.Number == 1205;
    }

    public static readonly DatabaseDeadlockTransientErrorDetectionStrategy Instance = new DatabaseDeadlockTransientErrorDetectionStrategy();
}
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
private static async Task RetryAsync()
{
    var retryStrategy = new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy(DatabaseDeadlockTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.Instance, retryStrategy);

    try
    {
        // Do some work that may result in a transient fault.
        await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
            async () =>
            {
                // TODO: replace with async ADO.NET calls.
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // All the retries failed.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I'm looking at Application Block now. mean while, is there a simple way to implement what I want?  I added some code to my example above to show what I want with await Task.Delay and it does not compile because of catch block error

Comment: Stephen, I'm trying the enterprise block and it seems it depends on a piece from azure store ('StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy'). I'm using ado.net to do my insert.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Do I have to use the async ado.net library? (I think that exists)

Comment: You don't need (and shouldn't be using) `StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen so much for the code. It would have taken me quite a while to get there on my own.  I'll put a blog post together that describes my complete trilogy of how I got here and the solution.  I'm surprised that this is not a more common problem that would be all over the internet.  Maybe because of the thousands of events I get fired back at me from sendgrid's event processor that causes me to do inserts is unusual.

Comment: I updated my question to include the final code combining part of what Stephen posted and the async ado.net

Comment: Stephen, The end of this story has not gone well.  I've posted my final code in the above question which basically, in the await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync("my lambda"), I wrap a sqlserver transaction that includes opening and closing a connection (using SqlConnection(...).  It caused sqlserver to spin out of control with 100's of connections and froze our server.  My working solution is to not do the retry logic and let sendgrid retry on non 200 returns.  I totally don't get why that would have happened but I do have a working solution

Comment: added the async ado.net insert method

Comment: @PeterKellner: That doesn't make sense. The retry code shouldn't even attempt a retry until after a second, and the SQL provider for .NET should be using connection pooling anyway.

Comment: Does not make sense to me either but it was easy to repro on local dev box by sending one request.  The retry logic would kick in.  Maybe I had something else wrong.